# How can I place text under a bracket\brace that isn't all one line

Tags: align, brackets, underbrace

I know how to create a text underneath a bracket. Note: my equation is fake, but I wanted to give you an example.

`\underbrace{203948x^{3}+209204024x^2-18909345x}_\text{How can I place a text that isn't on one long line, but aligned underneath the brace}`

Comment: The width of the textblock below the underbrace is supposed to be as wide as the math expression enclosed by the underbrace, right? Or should the textblock be wider than that -- or, maybe, narrower? Please advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could place the text in the second argument of `\underbrace` in a `\parbox` whose width is set to the width of the first argument of `\underbrace`. However, doing this manually can be tedious. Especially if you have several expressions like the one shown in your posting, it's a good idea to set up a dedicated macro to take care of the formatting chores. In the following example, this macro is called `\bigbrace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,ragged2e}

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\bigbrace[2]{%
   \settowidth\mylen{$\displaystyle #1$}
   \underbrace{#1}_{\parbox{\mylen}{\scriptsize\Centering #2}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\bigbrace{203948x^{3}+209204024x^2-18909345x}{How can I place a text
     that isn't on one long line, but aligned underneath the brace?}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of creating new commands for each arguments can I keep it blank? I don't really want to create a new one every time.

Comment: @Nixie777 - I've provided an addendum to show how to set up a single macro (called `\bigbrace`) which (a) acts like `\underbrace` and (b) constrains the width of the text material to be no greater than that of the math material it's associated with.

Comment: The *addendum* should be the main answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for your suggestion; I've edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

With `stackengine` for  manual line breaks, or defining a `\boxedunderbrace`command, based on the `eqparbox` package for an automatic line break: the text is placed in a `\parbox` of width equal to the formula width. It requires a tag as an optional argument (`M` by default) so as to differentiate multiple uses of `\boxedunderbrace`s. Two compilations are necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,ragged2e}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand\boxedunderbrace[3] [M] {\underbrace{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$} }_{\scriptsize\parbox{\eqboxwidth{#1}}{\centering#3}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\underbrace{203948x^{3}+209204024x^2-18909345x}_{\scriptsize\Centerstack{How can
     I place a text that isn't on one long\\ line, but aligned underneath
     the brace?}}
\]

\[
\boxedunderbrace[M]{203948x^{3}+209204024x^2-18909345x}{How can
I place a text that isn't on one long line, but aligned underneath the brace?}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to automate the insertion of a suitable line break in the argument of `\Centerstack`?

Comment: No, as far as I know (at least without writing a  macro). It's up to the user to decide where to break. Aesthetically, it's probably preferable.

Comment: @Mico: I've added an automatic solution, based on `eqparbox`.

Comment: @Mico While `stackengine` can stack `\parboxes`, it stacks delimited items, and thus is, itself, not a `\parbox`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Thanks for this clarification.